# How do I tell which TrueCrypt rescue disk applies to my currently encrypted system partition?

Tags: truecrypt

I've encrypted my system in the past and created a rescue disk, but for whatever reason I had to decrypt it. After reencrypting it, I created another rescue disk. However, I have a funny feeling that I've mixed up the two... I tried booting from both disks, and it was successful each time (odd, but regardless that doesn't help me find the correct disk).

Is there a way to tell if a rescue disk correctly corresponds to a particular partition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, figured it out...

In TrueCrypt, go to System > Verify Rescue Disk. It will fail on any disk but the correct one (note that it will prompt for administrative privileges to run this test).